# How to send an Object from one computer to another?

Tags: java, object, sockets

I know that the Java can use the Socket Programming to send an Object. Apart from socket programming, anything other way to do it?

Comment: it's just "java", not "the Java"

Comment: I dunno, I think it is like "The Google".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via web service for example. But its build on top on sockets again.

Comment: Yes web services are build on sockets but you don't have to work with them directly.

Answer (score 7):

Java's Remote Method Invocation ([RMI](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/rmi/index.jsp)) is probably the easiest and most widely supported way.

Java's [Advanced Socket Programming](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/sockets/) describes marshalling objects over a socket.

Comment: Using RMI (Remote Method Invocation) is probably an overkill and of course does involve sockets again.

Comment: Why is this overkill ? This seems entirely reasonable to me. I take your point about sockets, but (as everyone has pointed out) doing this *without* sockets seems a little, well, peculiar.

Comment: Aside from high speed robotic hands, carrier pigeons , rubber bands, or sneakernet, any practical way of sending data from one computer to another will involve sockets in some way or another.  It's just a mater of how well abstracted you are from the actual socket.

Comment: @Brian Agnew, because RMI has a gross API. :)

Answer (score 5):

Control a [high-speed robot hand](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KxjVlaLBmk&feature=player_embedded) to type it in.

Pretty well every other thing you can do will be a layer built on sockets.

Answer (score 4):

[RFC1149](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1149)!

Comment: While faster than sockets in some countries, I'd guess it isn't very practical :)

Comment: what, it's language-agnostic!

Comment: RFC is from 1990! and hosted by IETF itself!

Answer (score 3):

1. Attach rubber band to computer A
2. Put Object in rubber band.
3. Pull back, aim at Computer B.
4. Let go.

Answer (score 1):

[SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) (Simple Object Access Protocol).

Answer (score 1):

Serialize the object, write to a file, copy the file if the computers are network connected if not use a removable disk and deserialize it.

Answer (score 1):

Objects can be transferred via a **shared database**.

I work near a production system that's been doing this for 10 years.

Ironically, except in rare cases, DB connections are also implemented via sockets.

Answer (score 0):

No. Sockets are how computers communicate. Other than writing the data to some media and physically transporting it between computers, you will have to use sockets.

At the lowest level, data is transferred over sockets as bytes. So first you need to serialize your object to bytes, then you can send it, then on the other side you need to deserialize the object from the bytes.

Approaching your question less literally, there are Java libraries that handle the serialization automatically and hide the nastiness of dealing directly with sockets. I recommend [KryoNet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/). KryoNet can do [remote method invocations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), and a lot simpler and more efficiently than Java's built-in RMI support.